# Recover data from Win10 ReFS partition format on Windows7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, partition-recovery, refs

I had win10 installed, and another HD with one EFI partition.
Now I installed Win7 and forgot about that EFI partition. Everytime I try to read it...

> "  This windows version does not support ReFS format of partition A"

[image: Error]

Is there a way to recover the data ??

Comment: "Is there a way to recover the data??" - Use a Windows 8.1 or newer installation to view the contents of the partition.  What you want is not possible on Windows 7

Comment: Is there live CDs like linux or i HAVE to install it?

Comment: No; Absolutely Not; WinRE cannot be used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is no ReFS driver or support for Win7. Use Win10 to recover the data to an NTFS volume.

FROM:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReFS

> ReFS was initially added to Windows Server 2012 only, with the aim of gradual migration to consumer systems in future versions; this was achieved as of Windows 8.1

Comment: I dont have win10 installed no more :(

Comment: and you need it. You could use a Win10 boot CD or a VM.

Comment: is it possible to read that partition from a VM ? oO  
Like virtualbox ? Gee sounds too easy

Comment: It depends on how you have the hardware connected. You might be able to connect it raw: `9.9.1. Using a raw host hard disk from a guest`
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html

Comment: You would be better off with a boot CD or a dual boot situation.

Comment: Perfectly possible. You need to add the driver along it s corresponding registry entries.

Comment: @user2284570 you can just answer the question with actual instructions, instead of a vague comment. The only answer, mine, was correct back in 2017. Feel free to prove me wrong.